# Using regex to capture everything except a certain (possibly repeated) pattern

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to capture all of a string minus any occurrences of `<span class="notranslate">*any text*</span>` (i do NOT need to parse HTML or anything, i just need to ignore those whole sections. the tags must match exactly to be removed, because i want to keep other tags). In a given string there would be at least one tag, no upper limit (though more than a couple would be uncommon)

My ultimate goal is to match two texts, one where there are variable names and one where the variable names have been replaced with their values (can't replace the variables myself, I don't have access to that db). These variables will always be surrounded by the span tags I mentioned. I know my tags say "notranslate" - but this is pretranslation, so all of the other text will be exactly the same.

For example, if these are my two input texts:

> `Dear <span class="notranslate">$customer</span>, I am sorry that you
>   are having trouble logging in. Please follow the instructions at this
>   URL <span class="notranslate">$article431</span> and let me know if
>   that fixes your problem.`
>
> `Dear <span class="notranslate">John Doe</span>, I am sorry that you
>   are having trouble logging in. Please follow the instructions at this
>   URL <span class="notranslate">http://url.for.help/article</span> and
>   let me know if that fixes your problem.`

I want the regex to return:
`Dear , I am sorry that you are having trouble logging in. Please follow the instructions at this URL  and let me know if that fixes your problem.`
OR
`Dear <span class="notranslate"></span>, I am sorry that you are having trouble logging in. Please follow the instructions at this URL <span class="notranslate"></span> and let me know if that fixes your problem.`
For both of them, so I can easily do String.Equals() and find out if they are equal. (I will need to compare the input w/ variables against multiple texts where the variables have been replaced, to find the match)

I was easily able to come up with a regex that tells me whether a string has any "notranslate" sections in it: `(<span class="notranslate">(.+?)</span>)`, which is how i decide whether i need to strip out sections before comparison. However I'm having a lot of trouble with the (I thought very similar) task above.

I am using Expresso and regexstorm.net to test, and have played with many variations of `(?:(.+?)(?:<span class=\"notranslate\">(?:.+?)</span>))`, using ideas from other SO questions, but with all of them I get problems that I don't understand. For example, that one seems to almost work in Expresso but it can't grab the end text after the last set of span tags; when i make the span tags optional or try to add another (.+?) at the end it won't grab anything at all? I have tried using lookaheads, but then I still end up grabbing the tags+internal text later.

Comment: Can't you do a replace operation? Use your first regex, and then replace each match with an empty string.

Comment: Dear god. Yeah, that would work. I got psyched out about using regexes for the first time and developed tunnel vision. Thanks.

Comment: Phew! That's always a nice feeling when you realize it's easier than you thought. Glad I could help :)

Comment: You should considering using a html parser library to process the source. It would be much easier to remove the content of `span.notranslate` than working a regex for that. Also, you will be able to strip off all html tags, and keep only the text content.

Answer (score 0):

This will capture all, then process out the matched html tags which are ignored.

```
string data = "Dear <span class=\"notranslate\">$customer</span>, I am sorry that you\r\n  are havin" +
    "g trouble logging in. Please follow the instructions at this\r\n  URL <span class=" +
    "\"notranslate\">$article431</span> and let me know if\r\n  that fixes your problem.";

string pattern = @"(?<Words>[^<]+)(?<Ignore><[^>]+>[^>]+>)?";

Regex.Matches(data, pattern)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(mt => mt.Groups["Words"].Value)
     .Aggregate((sentance, words) => sentance + words );
```

The result is a string which has with the original carriage return and line feeds in your example actually:

```
Dear , I am sorry that you
  are having trouble logging in. Please follow the instructions at this
  URL  and let me know if
  that fixes your problem.
```